# How to Solve Mysterious <resources> Error in values.xml?

Tags: android

I want to make a button that moves to the website I want.
I wrote the same codes in the book.
But, the studio said it has 2 AAPT errors
I tried 'Alt+Enter' and fixed correct button name, but it didn't go well.
And I think errors in values.xml are the problems that they aren't in user's territory.

I used Android-studio 3.5. And my AVD is Nexus 5X.

`<resources><item name="button1" type="id">GEO</item></resources>` //in values/ids.xml

`[<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">][1]` //error in values.xml ;cannot find the declaration of element 'resources'

1. inner element must either be a resource reference or empty. ; in ids.xml
2. error: file failed to compile. ; build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this reference https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id to properly define your ID element - that's root cause of your issue I believe. In other words should be something like this:

```
<resources>
    <item name="button1" type="id" />
</resources>
```